# Small or large commit messages?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, cvs, dvcs

I friend of mine and I had a discussion a few days back about the size of a commit message when using version control systems. I had the idea of committing often and small when he on the other hand used larger commit message but instead committed not so often.

I've always heard that you should, at least as a beginner, do it my way; small commit messages often. You should, if possible, summarize your commit in one sentence.

But I get the opposite feeling when looking at pro's like [Linus Torvalds](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds). Here is one commit message from him on the [subsurface](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface) project on github.

> This makes it consider them to be identical if they are within half a
>   bar of each other.  If you edit the pressures by hand and set them to
>   the same bar pressure as the samples, they may not be identical to the
>   last milli-bar, but clearly the manually entered cylinder pressure isn't
>   significantly different from the sample data, so consider it redundant.
>   We do want manual overrides of cylinder pressures to take precedence
>   over sample data (as Dirk so eloquently puts it, some dive computers
>   really don't have very reliable sample data), but at the same time the
>   sample data is the one we are expecting to be fairly accurate.  The
>   starting and ending pressure overrides are for when there is no sample
>   data, or when the sample data is totally wrong for some reason.
>   Signed-off-by: Linus Torvalds

[Here](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface/commit/b4938ec2de87c3a43b749a1607d3bacb17d37cff) is the commit message in question.

I took a look at my own commit message (I've a few thousand of them) and they are most often always less than 40 characters.

Anyone got some input on the question?

Comment: This is soliciting opinion and debate rather than there actually being a specific answer. It would be better suited for community wiki rather than a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011471/proper-commit-messages  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321720/best-practices-for-version-control-comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598/suggestions-for-a-good-commit-message-format-guideline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to consider the audience for your commit messages.

If you are the only person ever to be interested in your projects, write as little as you feel like -- you just need enough to remind yourself why you chose one approach over another six months from now. You need just enough to find which specific commit changed which specific feature when you want to go bug-hunting.

If you are writing software with a team that might serve dozens or hundreds of people, the commit messages should probably be more meaningful. (This doesn't always mean *longer*, but it does mean "fix silly bug" is to be avoided at all costs -- "don't overrun stack buffer 'name'" is far better and almost as quick to type.)

Linus's commit messages might look huge, but he is not *verbose* or *wordy*. He's concise and gets to the point. He is writing for thousands or millions of programmers, distribution packagers, and in the specific commit message you found, divers *who depend on his code for their life*. They want better commit messages than might be demanded of a MMORPG checkin.

Answer (score 2):

The size of commit messages has *almost nothing* to do with how often you should commit.

The general consensus on commit frequency is that committing often is better, but you should commit only code that works (or at least compiles and doesn't break anything).

Note that git allows you to "squash" multiple commits into a single one, so that you get the benefit of committing often (not having many uncommitted changes at any time) and committing only complete features (more easily understood commit history.

As for commit messages, more information is always good but of course should be weighed against the effort it requires.

The point of a commit message is to give a very brief overview of what was changed (so that you can decide whether it's interesting to you when looking at the commit history), and explain *why* the change in the commit was done. Linus' message does this in great detail. But if there is a corresponding entry in an issue/bug tracking system, or a design document, it would be better to refer to that.

Comment: "commit only code that works (or at least compiles and doesn't break anything)" is **not general consensus**, but only *widely used* (see difference)

Comment: "commit only code that works (or at least compiles and doesn't break anything)" It sound like you're using something like SVN. Torvalds is talking about this particular problem [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8&t=22m27s). I can't come up with a reason anyone would do that in a decentralized environment.

Comment: @Oleander: It's true that in a distributed environment, local commits that break the build are not problematic per se. But they do become problematic when they're pushed to other repositories, even if they're pushed as a batch that overall leads to compilable, working code - because someone wanting to pull selectively now has to be very careful to pull the whole batch. Which is where commit squashing enters the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer smaller commit messages with atomic commits. Commit small, succinct changes. They don't require much explanation. Write the code, and if it needs explaining let the comments do the talking. It's hard to scan commits with huge messages. As long as you explain the gist of what's going on, that should be good enough. I guess it does boil down to personal preference though.

Answer (score 1):

Size of my commits depends on my tasks. 
I try group similar changes in one commit. So, messages only describes features that I develop (without long and boring stories).

Answer (score 0):

Little and often is what I find works best